# UI updates using BeginInvoke hung until thread completes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, forms, invoke

I have 1 class (acBL) which handles 2 threads (fpDoWork). Any work that is done in fpDoWork will trigger an event back to the acBL class. On my form I declare the acBL class and associate Event handlers on acBL - this way whenever the event is called, it 'should' update the UI with changes.

What is not happening is, when each fpDoWork thread is started, it performs the operations, the ProcessingEvent is called and does go into the frmMain.handlerProcessing1 event. It gets to the point where this.BeginInvoke(new Processing2Event (handlerProcessing2), status) is called, then it just hangs and waits until the thread has finished its work before continuing to update the UI. I tried this.Invoke, but that method just seems to hang. Any ideas?

Code inside frmMain

Earlier in the code:

```
this.acBL.Processing1Event += new acBL.Processing1(handlerProcessing1);
this.acBL.Processing2Event += new acBL.Processing2(handlerProcessing2);
```

Handlers:

```
private void handlerProcessing1(string status) {
  if (InvokeRequired) {
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Refresh));
    this.BeginInvoke(new Processing1Event (handlerProcessing1), status);

  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("UPDATING 1: "+status);
    lblForProcessing1.Text = status;
    this.Refresh();
    return;
  }
}


private void handlerProcessing2(string status) {
  if (InvokeRequired) {
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Refresh));
    this.BeginInvoke(new Processing2Event (handlerProcessing2), status);

  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("UPDATING 2: "+status);
    lblForProcessing2.Text = status;
    this.Refresh();
    return;
  }
}
```

Code inside acBL

In a main method:

```
bool thread1Complete = false;
fpDoWork fpDoWork1 = new fpDoWork();
fpDoWork1.GUIForm = frmMain;
fpDoWork1.ProcessingEvent += new fpDoWork.Processing(handlerProcessing1Event);
fpDoWork1.ThreadCompleteEvent += new fpDoWork.ThreadComplete(thread1Complete);
Thread fpDoWork1Thread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(fpDoWork1.StartWork));

bool thread2Complete = false;
fpDoWork fpDoWork2 = new fpDoWork();
fpDoWork2.GUIForm = frmMain;
fpDoWork2.ProcessingEvent += new fpDoWork.Processing(handlerProcessing2Event);
fpDoWork2.ThreadCompleteEvent += new fpDoWork.ThreadComplete(thread2Complete);
Thread fpDoWork2Thread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(fpDoWork2.StartWork));

Console.WriteLine("Work for 1 Thread started...");
fpDoWork1Thread.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Work for 2 Thread started...");
fpDoWork2Thread.Start();

while (!thread1Complete && !thread2Complete ) {
  if (!thread1Complete && !thread2Complete ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for both copying threads...");
  }
  else if (!thread1Complete && thread2Complete ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for thread 1...");
  }
  else if (thread1Complete && !thread2Complete ) {
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for thread 2...");
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.WriteLine("All done");
```

Else where in the code:

```
public delegate void ProcessingFor1 (string filename);
public delegate void ProcessingFor2 (string filename);
public event ProcessingFor1 ProcessingEventFor1;
public event ProcessingFor2 ProcessingEventFor2;


private void handlerProcessing1Event(string filename) {
  Console.WriteLine("Processing 1: " + filename);
  ProcessingEventFor1(filename);
}

private void handlerProcessing1Event(string filename) {
  Console.WriteLine("Processing 2: " + filename);
  ProcessingEventFor2(filename);
}
```

Comment: You are creating deadlock by blocking the UI thread, looping on the flags.  The BeginInvoke target cannot run until the UI thread goes idle, back to pumping the message loop.  You should *never* ever block the UI thread.

Avoid re-inventing the hurt, use BackgroundWorker.  And don't loop on its IsBusy property, same problem.  Do whatever you want to do after the thread completes in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: I dont have time to recode to incorporate BackgroundWorker. I did try to implement it before but found limitations. Is there a way I can fix the deadlock in this scenario?

Comment: Hans' comment is correct. Fixing deadlocks do take time. I second his motion that you invest the time to fix it correctly. Any hacked-together solution (such as a nested message loop) will only cause weird bugs for you to deal with in the future; it would save you a lot of time to fix it earlier instead of later.

Comment: @Nobugz: I've seen you answer a lot of questions with comments instead of answers. Any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

the reason your UI is not updating is that the primary UI thread is stuck in your **while**() loop.  **BackgroundWorker** is your friend

try to avoid creating threads in one thread and sit there waiting for them to finish, its a bad use of threads in the first place

cheers